# Prove that intervals $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic without using connectedness properties

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to prove this statement, but having troubles with using notion of continuity.

The closest answer I found on stackexchange that matches the question is from Tarc (last answer):

[Prove that an open interval and a closed interval are not homeomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784165/prove-that-an-open-interval-and-a-closed-interval-are-not-homeomorphic)

Still, I don't quite comprehend the last paragraph:

> Suppose $f: [a,b] \to (c, d)$ is a homeomorphism. Observe that $f(a)\not=f(b)$ as $f$ is injective and consider the point $f(a)+f(b)\over 2$ at half the distance between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. As $f$ is surjective, $f(x) = {f(a)+f(b)\over 2 }$ for some $x \in [a,b]$.
>
> Now let $\delta$ be enough for both the distances between $f(x)$ and $f(a)$, and between $f(x)$ and $f(b)$ to be less than $\delta$ and yet the open interval centered at $f(x)$ of radius $\delta$ not to cover the whole $(c,d)$.
>
> As $f$ is continuous, there must be an open interval centered at $x$ large enough to contain both $a$ and $b$ and whose image under $f$ is within a distance of $\delta$ from $f(x)$. As such an interval must ecompass the whole $[a,b]$, the function $f$ cannot be surjective for $\delta$ is chosen in such a way that there're points in $(c,d)$ with a distance from $f(x)$ greater than $\delta$.

P.S.
Without using connectedness properties -- that means no intermediate value theorem either.

UPDATE.
Background of the task: This is one of the exercises from book on differential topology. Author didn't introduce notions of compactness or connectedness yet. So that's why I am wondering how to prove the claim w/o using them.

Comment: It's hard to prove without any notion of (or derived fact from) either compactness or connectedness, I think.

Comment: I'd think that in a book on differential topology calculus is assumed at least, so the intermediate value theorem for intervals and the extreme-value theorem for bounded closed real intervals are OK to use. You don't need the general theorems. Any good calculus/real analysis course has these esential theorems.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok, thanks. Does that mean that there is an error in the proof that I quoted?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, got it. I guess quoted proof missed the part about intermediate value theorem. Then it looks ok..

Comment: Indeed I suspect any book on differential topology assumes some familiarity with compactness as well and this was the likely avenue the authors intended readers to take.

Comment: Compactness is introduced few pages later. Given that solution is found (thanks to @HennoBrandsma, comment above), w/o referring to connectivity or compactness, I think this was the way author meant in this exercise.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if they were homemorphic then there is a continuous bijection $\;[0,1]\to (0,1)\;$ , which would make $\;(0,1)\;$ compact just as $\;[0,1]\;$ is...

Comment: Added an update to the task. Compactness is not "allowed" either..

Comment: Then you add an update to the exercise's solution: "You have got to be kidding!"

Answer (score 0):

Compactness of $[0,1]$ is the easiest way. Or use the derived fact that a continuous function on $[0,1]$ has a maximum and a minumum. If the minimum is $m \in (0,1)$ for a continuous $f:[0,1] \to (0,1)$, then $f$ cannot be onto, as the values in $(0,m)$ are not assumed by $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I need new glasses (or my mind is going)! I answered the wrong question. I thought one interval was half-open and half-closed. But no harm, the arguments are very similar.

---

A student has completed his study of [Infima and suprema of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Infima_and_suprema_of_real_numbers) and then learns the definitions for a topological space and continuous functions. He understands that

$\tag 1 f(\overline{A})\subseteq \overline{f(A)}$

whenever $f$ is continuous.

The student also learns about the two point discrete space $D = \{0,1\}$, and then works out the details for the following:

Proposition 1: There is no continuous surjective function $f: \mathbb R \to D$; in fact, there is no continuous surection of $\mathbb R$ onto any finite discrete space.
Proof
There is an open interval about the number $0$ such that all the numbers in that interval get mapped to the same point $f(0)$. Assume that there are real numbers that do not get mapped to $f(0)$. But then (a non-empty closed set of real numbers bounded from, say below, has a least element), there is a continuous function

$\tag 2 g: (a, b]: \to D \; \text{ with } a \lt 0 \lt b$
such that
$\quad g \text{ is constant and equal to } f(0) \text{ on the open interval } (a, b)$
$\quad g(b) \ne f(0)$

But this is absurd by (1). $\quad \blacksquare$

After some help from a Calculus Professor, he can claim without apology that the open interval $(0,1)$ is homeomorpihc to $\mathbb R$.

She then proves, without undue difficulty nor reading chapter 2 of his topology book, that $(0,1)$ can't be homeomorpic $(0,1]$.

Logic: If you remove any point from $(0,1)$ the result is the disjoint topological sum,

$\tag 3 \mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R$

If you remove $\{1\}$ from $(0,1]$ the result is $\mathbb R$.

If the intervals are homeomorphic, then both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R$ must be, but that is absurd.

---

Now we answer the stated question...

If you remove any one point from the open interval $(0,1)$ and remove another single point from the resulting space, you are looking at, up to a homeomorphism,

$\tag 4 \mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R$

But if you first take out $\{0\}$ from $[0,1]$ and then $\{1\}$, you are looking at $\mathbb R$. So the open and closed interval can't be homeomorphic.